# Replacing the first string character in python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, replace

i have a pandas series like this:

```
0          $233.94
1          $214.14
2          $208.74
3          $232.14
4          $187.15
5          $262.73
6          $176.35
7          $266.33
8          $174.55
9          $221.34
10         $199.74
11         $228.54
12         $228.54
13         $196.15
14         $269.93
15         $257.33
16         $246.53
17         $226.74
```

i want to get rid of the dollar sign so i can convert the values to numeric. I made a function in order to do this:

```
def strip_dollar(series):
    for number in dollar:
        if number[0] == '$':
            number[0].replace('$', ' ')

    return dollar
```

This function is returning the original series untouched, nothing changes, and i don't know why.

Any ideas about how to get this right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `df['col'].str.replace("$", "")` ?

Comment: nonono :). You shuld use pd.to_numeric() but replace $ first.

Comment: replace is String function so first you should convert the values to string and then you replace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`lstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html) and convert to `float`s:

```
s = s.str.lstrip('$').astype(float)
print (s)
0     233.94
1     214.14
2     208.74
3     232.14
4     187.15
5     262.73
6     176.35
7     266.33
8     174.55
9     221.34
10    199.74
11    228.54
12    228.54
13    196.15
14    269.93
15    257.33
16    246.53
17    226.74
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

**Setup**:

```
s = pd.Series(['$233.94', '$214.14', '$208.74', '$232.14', '$187.15', '$262.73', '$176.35', '$266.33', '$174.55', '$221.34', '$199.74', '$228.54', '$228.54', '$196.15', '$269.93', '$257.33', '$246.53', '$226.74'])
print (s)
0     $233.94
1     $214.14
2     $208.74
3     $232.14
4     $187.15
5     $262.73
6     $176.35
7     $266.33
8     $174.55
9     $221.34
10    $199.74
11    $228.54
12    $228.54
13    $196.15
14    $269.93
15    $257.33
16    $246.53
17    $226.74
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help @jezrael. I marked this answer as correct because i didn't know the `lstrip` method. Nice and clever. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.replace("$", "")`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col" : ["$233.94", "$214.14"]})
df["Col"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Col"].str.replace("$", ""))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
      Col
0  233.94
1  214.14
```

Answer (score 2):

**CODE:**

```
ser = pd.Series(data=['$123', '$234', '$232', '$6767'])
def rmDollar(x):
    return x[1:]
serWithoutDollar = ser.apply(rmDollar)
serWithoutDollar
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0     123
1     234
2     232
3    6767
dtype: object
```

*Hope it helps!*